# FFPopup Pod: Hide Popup when not used

Tags: ios, swift, popup, cocoapods, hide

:)
I'm working with [this cocoa pod](https://github.com/JonyFang/FFPopup) and have some issues.
When I start the app, the popup is already presented (not called it with showPopup()).
I tried to hide it with isHidden but that does not work properly.
Does anyone knows how I can do this:

Always hide the view (popup) and only present it if showPopup() is called, then hide it when pressed anywhere (like it already does).

This is an example code:

```
     @IBOutlet weak var popupView: UIView!

      override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            [...]
            popupView.isHidden = true // tried to hide it from the beginning and show it when needed
        }

     func showPopup() {
            popupView.isHidden = false
            let popup = FFPopup(contetnView: popupView, showType: .bounceIn, dismissType: .shrinkOut, maskType: .dimmed, dismissOnBackgroundTouch: true, dismissOnContentTouch: false)
            let layout = FFPopupLayout(horizontal: .center, vertical: .center)
            popup.show(layout: layout, duration: 5)
        }

    //HELP!!!!! Need some kind of listener who detects if popup view is closed or not?
    func popupDismissedDetected(){ // only an example, of course not works like this...
            popupView.isHidden = true
        }
    func needPopupNow(){
            showPopUp()
        }
```

I hope my problem is clear now. Does anyone has an idea of how to handle this?

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure if this is a problem but `let popup = FFPopup(contetnView:` should be `let popup = FFPopup(contentView:` (contentView is misspelled)

Comment: Thanks @aheze but thats not my mistake, the typo is in the pod itself

Comment: Oh, haha. Also, how come the popup is already presented when you start the app? Or is it not presented, but `popupView` is shown? I think you might be confusing the popup and `popupView`...